# Reportbuilder 2012 3.0 One line for all registrations instead of the amount of registrations + Only one sommation

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I'm making an overview of the registered hours in Reportbuilder but I can't seem to get my report just like how I want it. I want everything on one line and not diagonal under each other. Also it should just give a sommation once per project. Not for the amount of registrations that are booked on it. Is it even possible? Underneath is the query I use, followed by images of the problem and what it should be like + the table used in Reportbuilder.

Thanks in advance

```
SELECT emp.FirstName + ' ' + emp.LastName AS Name, SUM(reg.DurationHours) 
FROM   Employee AS emp LEFT OUTER JOIN
       Registration AS reg ON emp.EmployeeId = reg.EmployeeId 
AND reg.RegistrationDate >= @StartDate AND reg.RegistrationDate <= @EndDate 
AND reg.IsOutOfHours = 0  
GROUP BY emp.FirstName + ' ' + emp.LastName;
```

Example of my problem and how it should be.

[image: Image of the problem]

This is the image of the table I use in Reporting Services to get to that result.

[image: Table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find an answer to my own question. I added a grouping on Reference in the Details like shown in the following images:

1. Right click on Details in the Row Groups Menu and open Group Properties

[image: Step 1]

2. Add a Group on Reference

   [image]
3. Problem solved